# PGFplots (windows and linux) compile problem

Tags: pgfplots, miktex, texlive, windows, linux

So I am writing a report with a group where I am using Debian with texlive and my groupmates are on both Win 7 and Win 8 with miktex.

I have made some plots using PGFplot on my machine, looks like this

```
\documentclass[12pct]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[danish]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath , amsfonts , amssymb}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
  title = $\theta_{arm}$ som funktion af tiden,
  xlabel=$t$,
  ylabel=$\theta_{arm}$,
  ytick={1, 1.5, 2, 2.5, 3,3.5, 4, 4.5, 5}
  ]
\addplot [blue] table {theta_arm.dat};
\addlegendentry{$\theta_{arm}(t)$}

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

with a .dat file like this

```
0   1.57079632679490
0.0100000000000000  1.57101942671423
0.0200000000000000  1.57168870522067
0.0300000000000000  1.57280410752281
0.0400000000000000  1.57436554186042
0.0500000000000000  1.57637287884632
0.0600000000000000  1.57882595054590
0.0700000000000000  1.58172454929509
0.0800000000000000  1.58506842625795
0.0900000000000000  1.58885728972526
```

But when one of my groupmates tries to compile, he gets an error related to pgfplots. I have made sure the package is installed via miktex package installer (admin). He is using texmaker as editor

Can anyone help me with this problem, or clarify if miktex and handle pgfplots without any subcompile like with eps-files

Comment: Which error? Do you both have the same version of `pgfplots`? Is the `.dat` file in the same relative directory to the `.tex` file?

Comment: I haven't checked if we have same versions, but would that be a problem, with such a simple plot? and I have pointed to where the .dat file is, and it works fine when I compile

I have updated my post to something working if you create a .dat file

Comment: I don't know, it was just to rule out possible causes. It would be helpful if you could post the entire error your friend sees as well, at the moment it is sort of impossible to say what could be wrong (for me at least), your code works fine here as well.

Comment: Your dat file can have different line end and column separators. One of you might be eating the tab separators etc. without the error we can't help.